# Deploy an application with dockerised frontend and dockerise backend images

Tags: reactjs, docker, go, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am currently working on an application using Reactjs as front end and Golang as backend.
My folder structure and my docker-compose.yml[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3qpL.png) is as below
[docker-compose.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnCKe.png).My application is working fine locally .I wan to deploy it into a free hosting site.I want to deploy backend dockerised image and get a link for it and use it in reactjs front end files and dockerise the frontend and deploy front end as well so that I can access it from anywhere.
Please help me .Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "deploy the frontend"? The frontend runs in the browser. It not "deployed" as such. Just have your Go server serve the HTML/JS/CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [docker hub](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/) or self-hosted [docker registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/#:%7E:text=The%20Registry%20is%20a%20stateless,under%20the%20permissive%20Apache%20license.)

You can use docker-compose commands as below

first, build your docker image

```sh
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up --build -d
```

then, set a tag for the image. (I assume you signed up in docker hub with `hub-username` and create a repo named it `server-repo`)

the tag-name can be anything, I use app version like v1.0.0

```sh
docker tag go-docker:latest hub-username/server-repo:v1.0.0
```

finally, push it to the docker hub

```sh
docker push hub-username/server-repo:v1.0.0
```

in your server you can use a docker-compose file like this:

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:

  go-docker:
    image: hub-username/server-repo:v1.0.0
    container_name: go-api
    restart: always
```

If you want to use a self-hosted docker registry instead of docker hub, the only change is that you should prepend the registry address to the repo-name everywhere you used repo-name (docker tag and push commands, as well as in your server docker-compose file), like this:

`registry.mydomain.io:5000/registry-username/server-repo:v1.0.0`